# Shrinking size of text in text block as per need basis in GoJS

Tags: gojs

I have :

myDiagram.nodeTemplate followed by myDiagram.groupTemplate.

The text block in nodetemplate has width of 60 (needs this so that it is consistent across all diagrams).

I have font: "normal 10pt Georgia" for the text to be displayed.

Currently if the text is large it gets cutoff. please see imgae:

[image]

Is it possible to to shrink the size of the text to fit in the text block? I am ok if the font size changes dynamically. How can I achieve this?

I tried to experiment with wrap properties but it didnt work. 
i cannot change height of textbox.

Any help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Viewbox Panel.

See the last example on this page: http://gojs.net/latest/intro/panels.html